# Angular2 - Update model on button click

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

When using the angular2 ngModel for two-way data binding:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="heroName">
```

Is there a way to only update the model once a button is clicked? Or be able to cancel the changes that the user made to the input control? I am aware of the other approach where we can split the `[(ngModel)]` in its `[]` and `()` and only update the input on blur or when the Enter key is pressed etc - but this is not what I want.

I need this behavious because, the user must be able to cancel the changes.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do following for that,

**DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/OW61kGGcxV5MuRlY8VO4?p=preview**

```
{{heroName}}<br>
<input [ngModel]="heroName" #change> <br>
<br>
<button (click)="update(change.value)">Update Model</button>
```

---

```
export class App {
  heroName="Angular2";
  update(value){
    console.log('value before button click' + this.heroName);
    this.heroName=value;
    console.log('value after button click' + this.heroName);
  }
}
```

Comment: `[()]` syntax internally updates model without your permission. so you should opt for other way.

Comment: This is interesting and what I want. But is there another framework-built-in way of doing it or this is the only way by using the template variable?

Comment: other framework-built-in way means what? its Angular2 way syntax only. I'm not sure but its easiest way I guess to update model only with click event.

Comment: You said you already looked into `[]()` syntax so I think next solution is this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new property for the form binded property.

Would look like this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="formHeroName" #change> <br>
{{selectedHeroName}}
<br>
```

Update Model
   Cancel

```
export class App implements OnInit {
selectedHeroName="Angular2";
formHeroName = "";

ngOnInit() {
  this.formHeroName = this.selectedHeroName;
}

update(){
  this.selectedHeroName= this.formHeroName;
}

cancel() {
  this.formHeroName = this.selectedHeroName;
}
}
```

See plunker for example - http://plnkr.co/edit/0QEubJDzlgs0CdnKrS8h?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for a way where I don't have to introduce new state variables.

Comment: without keeping track of the differences between original/updated variables, how are you achieving the cancelling of the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your "live" data from your "valid" data.

Try something like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="live.heroName">
<button (click)="save()">Save</button>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

And the controller:

```
live = { heroName: '', heroPower: '' };
valid = { heroName: '', heroPower: '' };

save() {
    this.valid = Object.assign({}, this.live);
}

reset() {
    this.live = Object.assign({}, this.valid);
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been thinking about, but it becomes quite verbose if you have to do this for every input. Thanks :)