# Angular2 ngModel in form. Prevent updating the underlying model

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have these properties in a component defined as such.

```
userDataDefinitions:Array<userDataDefinition>;
currentDefinition:userDataDefinition = null;
```

I then have a form, which displays data in accordance to the currentDefinition, which is set as such:

```
<div *ngFor="let userDataDefinition of userDataDefinitions">
            <a href="#" (click)="setCurrentDefinition(userDataDefinition)">
              {{ userDataDefinition.key }}
            </a>
        </div>
```

The form input fields use ngModel as such:

```
[(ngModel)]="currentDefinition.property"
```

This means that as soon as I edit one of the input fields, the underlying currentDefinition AND userDataDefinitions are updated instantly, as expected.
My question is what should I do if I want the underlying model to be updated ONLY upon an action (such as the form submit)?
Should I clone the currentDefinition? Should I not use ngModel?

What is the correct angular2 way to achieve this result?

Thank you very much

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do a one-way binding from the property to the view and only update the property on a event of your choice. Here is a sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/lNcp7vcEGkozTzB8w4OT?p=info

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <div>
          <label>{{name}}</label>
          <input type="text" [ngModel]="name" />
          <button (click)="name = 'change'">Change</button>
        </div>
      `,
    })
    export class App {
      name:string;
      constructor() {
        this.name = 'Angular2'
      }
    }

    @NgModule({
      imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ App ],
      bootstrap: [ App ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
{{heroName}}<br> 
<input [(ngModel)]="heroName" #change> <br> <br>
<button (click)="update(change.value)">Update Model</button>
```

With the "#" you have a reference to the objekt that is changing, if you then click the button you send your information as parameter.

Take a look to this question for more details

[Angular2 - Update model on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224324/angular2-update-model-on-button-click)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14187529)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Stefan